# Filtering data between dates - how to get data between months?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimepicker, rowfilter

I've got a .NET control which reads data from a SQL database and displays it in a DataGridView. I use the DateTimePicker to filter the data between two dates. This works fine when I'm within the same month, for example 28. June - 30. June, but if I set 1. July as the end date then I get no data. Date is stored as datetime in the database. Do you know what could be wrong? Here is my code for the DateTimePicker when the value is changed.

```
private void dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dtpStartDate and dtpEndDate are my DateTimePickers
    DateTime start = dtpStartDate.Value;
    DateTime end = dtpEndDate.Value;
    dateFilter = string.Format("([{0}] >= '{1}' AND [{0}] <= '{2}')", "Date", start, end);
    dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = dateFilter;
}
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Did your dates stored in the database contain also the hour,minutes,seconds part with a significant value (not 00.00.00)?

Comment: If you have more info, please edit your question and not put stuff in comments. And, did you debug the string actually generated?

Comment: @Steve The Date is stored like this in the database: 2014-06-26 14:23:59.540

Comment: And what is the value of the dateFilter when you don't retrieve any value? Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line after the one that sets the dateFilter variable and check the value produced by your expression.

Comment: @Steve it's  "([Date] >= '30/06/2014 11:06:00' AND [Date] <= '01/07/2014 11:06:59')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. This solved the problem:

```
private void dtpEndDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dtpStartDate and dtpEndDate are my DateTimePickers
    string start = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpStartDate.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff");
    string end = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEndDate.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff");
    dateFilter = string.Format("([{0}] >= #{1}# AND [{0}] <= #{2}#)", "Date", start, end);
    dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = dateFilter;
}
```